# nginx - ssl and www redirect configuration

Tags: ssl, http, https, nginx, www

this is related to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538973/django-allowed-hosts-error-for-www-domain-and-ip-address

i'm attempting to redirect www and non-ssl requests to ssl non-www domain for my site. i'm running nginx for front end webserver

unfortunately i continue to have a couple issues:
* if i run https://www.domain.com, i get an http400
* i still get errors from underlying application that it is recieving requests on www.domain.com and < ipaddress >

Can someone help point out what is wrong with my conf below?

```
server {
    listen <ip address>:80;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
}


server{
    listen <ip address>:80;

    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

#HTTPS server
server{
    listen <ip address>:80;
    listen <ip address>:443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:<path to socket file>;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;    
    }

    if ($ssl_protocol = ""){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

}
```